# I am trying to add a dropdown list in default registration form to capture data from database in laravel 7

Tags: laravel

I get this error Undefined variable: areas (View: D:\newWamp\htdocs\networks\resources\views\auth\register.blade.php)

I have added this to my view registration blade

```
                 <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('areas') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                 <label for="town_id" class="col-md-4 control-label">Select your Area</label>
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                      <select class="form-control" name="area_id" id="area_id">
                      <option value="">Select your Area</option>
                     @foreach ($areas as $area)
                      <option value="{{ $area->id }}">{{ $town->id }}</option>
                     @endforeach
                      </select>
                     @if ($errors->has('areas'))
                         <span class="help-block">
                             <strong>{{ $errors->first('areas') }}</strong>
                         </span>
                     @endif
                 </div>
             </div>
```

And in my controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use App\location;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers;
    protected $redirectTo = '/user';
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
protected function showTowns(){
  $areas = DB::table('locations')->get();
  return view('auth.register', ['area' => $areas]);
}
```

and my web routes

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Auth::routes();
Route::get('auth.register', 'auth.RegisterController@showTowns');
```

I there a way I can capture the areas to a selection in registration form. Any help or guidance will be appreciated

Comment: `'areas' =>  DB::table('locations')->get()` here key should be `areas`

Comment: Which function uses  the `register.blade.php` balde file here?

Comment: you should  try like this  return view('auth.register', compact('areas'));  in controller

Comment: @Kamlesh I have edited the function is showTowns()

Comment: `['area' => $areas]` to `['areas' => $areas]`

Answer (score 1):

```
protected function showTowns(){
    $areas = DB::table('locations')->get();
    return view('auth.register', ['area' => $areas]);
}
```

you pass wrong varible name to view, change the `['area' => $areas]` to `['areas' => $areas]` and your code will work

Comment: getting this error Undefined variable: areas